# Problema com IF/ELSE e variáveis

Tags: python, variáveis, if, else

Comecei a estudar Python a pouco tempo, e criei o seguinte código:

```
gene = open("AY365046.1.txt","r")

g=0;
a=0;
c=0;
t=0;

gene.readline()

for line in gene:
    line = line.lower()
    for char in line:
        if char == "g":
            g+=1
        if char == "a":
            a+=1
        if char == "c":
            c+=1
        if char == "t":
            t+=1

print "Guanina: " + str(g)
print "Adenina: " + str(a)
print "Citosina: " + str(c)
print "Timina: " + str(t)

gc = (g+c+0.) / (a+t+c+g+0.)

print "Conteúdo GC: " +str(gc)
```

O criei utilizando como base um tutorial básico, e adaptei conforme eu desejava...

Agora quero deixa-lo interativo... Meu objetivo é utilizar a função **input()** para obter o número da sequencia na qual será exibido os dados...

No código acima, ele obtêm apenas os dados de uma sequência (AY365046.1.txt)... Portanto, preciso que o código tenha acesso a mais arquivos .txt (como por exemplo **sequencia2.txt** e **sequencia3.txt**), e  que ele obtenha os dados de **g**, **a**, **c** e **t** do arquivo informado no **input()**...

Exemplo:

1) Sistema pede número da sequência

2) Usuário informa **sequencia2**

3) Sistema obtenha informações de **sequencia2.txt**

4) **g**, **a**, **c** e **t** sejam obtidos do **sequencia2.txt** e exibidos através do **print()**

5) E caso seja informado uma sequencia inexistente, como por exemplo, **sequencia5**, seja informado uma mensagem de erro...

Até onde entendi, para realizar tudo isso basta eu declarar as variáveis, atribuir os arquivos .txt a cada uma delas, e criar um if/else...

O problema é que tentei de todas as formas descobrir como realizar isso, e não consegui...

Obviamente não precisam criar o código pra mim, mas... Podem me dizer ao menos por onde devo começar? O meu raciocínio do que devo fazer está correto? Falta algo?

Obrigado!

Comment: Você deve começar postando o que você tentou e os problemas que teve. Caso contrário só resta fazer por você já que você definiu como fazer. Dicas: tenta resolver um problema de cada vez. Até os programadores mais experientes fazem isto. Primeiro faça o nome do arquivo ser pedido para o usuário (passo 1). O passo 2 não é algo que se coloca no código, esquece ele. O 3 você já faz, só falta o nome ser a variável obtida. O 4 já faz. O 5 é outro problema e você não definiu o que é uma sequencia inexistente. Posta o que fez e eu posto uma resposta.

Comment: Sugiro você usar o Python 3 que é o futuro da linguagem. As mudanças que você terá que fazer para que este seu script funcione são mínimas. No teu caso é só mudar os prints de (exemplo) `print "banana"` para `print("banana")`

Answer (score 1):

Teu código tá praticamente pronto, o que resta é colocar ele dentro de um loop e receber o nome do arquivo do usuário.

Ficaria algo como:

```
run = True
while run:
    # Pega sequência do usuário
    sequence = input("Insira a sequencia:")

    # Tenta abrir o arquivo da sequencia
    try:
        gene = open("sequence ","r")
    catch IOError:
        print("Sequencia nao encontrada")
        # Interrompe essa iteracao e vai para a proxima
        continue

    # Todo o resto do teu código aqui
    # Quando terminar, seta o run pra False para interromper o loop
```

**Lembre-se de sempre fechar o arquivo ao final do loop**

```
gene.close()
```